# How do I load styles for editing the admin interface for the block builder?

Tags: block-editor

I'd like to style the block builder interface.
Specifically, I'd like to alter the margins around the outside of the block builder "canvas".

My understanding is that if I simply load a stylesheet for the block builder to load, some rules will not be applied. Specifically, those rules that apply to the interface itself.

My understanding is that to edit the style of the block builder canvas, I should use the 'enqueue_block_editor_assets' action hook.

I have the following function.
It does fire, but the stylesheet isn't being requested by the admin page.

```
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'style_block_builder');

    function style_block_builder() {    
        wp_enqueue_style(
        'block-editor-ui-styles', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/block-editor-interface.css'
        );
    }
```

Comment: "*the margins around the outside of the block builder "canvas"*" - can you show a screenshot of that and/or an example CSS rule which you're trying to apply?

Comment: @SallyCJ if it's easier to think about, consider a border around the editor canvas that I don't want to appear in the page that the editor outputs. By default the block editor canvas has no border. But a developer might want to give it one by styling the container.

Comment: @SallyCJ as stated initially, the resource is not being requested. No http request is issued for the stylesheet.

Comment: I had that in mind, but it just wasn't 100% clear simply by saying "*the stylesheet isn't being requested*".. ✌

Comment: So my question now is, where did you put the code - in the theme's `functions.php` file? Is that the entire code or did you omit anything like an if-else check?

Comment: For some context, are you working with an existing block theme or a classic theme?